# pdftk not able to open file

Tags: pdftk, xfdf

I am trying to fill data into a pdf from a xfdf file.

```
pdftk /templates/pdf/2018/data_file_1.pdf fill_form /tmp/input_xfdf.xfdf output /tmp/output.pdf
```

But It is showing this error.

```
Error: Failed to open form data file: 
   /tmp/input_xfdf.xfdf
   No output created.
```

I have tried [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533839/why-is-pdftk-saying-it-cant-find-files-that-are-right-there) also and have given folder access.

Comment: Since you are linking to the answer about snaps, does this mean you are running the snap version? If so, is the problem with snap or with pdftk? Which steps did you try to debug this?